# How to convert fabric js text to pdf

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

I'am using **fabricjs** to create a poster( containg text and images).

For font family(like lobster) I'am using google fonts. I save the poster in .svg format(using `fabric.toSVG()`) on  server. I'am trying to generate pdf using **Apache FOP** (I also tried rsvg, cariosvg and phantomjs rasterize) but they are not able to embed font family correctly.

Problem is because they cannot find css for that particular font. I used  to provide the path of css, but still generated pdf contains no font family.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Apache FOP provides you the facility of adding font matrix.
I solved my problem my downloading fonts from googlefont directory and creating a conf file for Apache FOP. In the conf file I mentioned the path to directory. I use -c option to run configs from font file.
Added below line to conf.xml file

```
<directory recursive="true">/var/www/pic/fonts</directory>
```